# How to make an implementation take type precedence in TypeScript

Tags: class, typescript, types, interface

In TypeScript, I have an interface: `SimpleMessage`, and numerous implementations of it. The interface has a member, `type`, which serves to identify the type of message.

An implementation would look like this:

```
class Implementation implements SimpleMessage
{
   public readonly type = MessageType.Foo;
   /* Other stuff */
}
```

I also have a union type, `AnyMessage`, which is a union of `SimpleMessage` and all implementations. If I compare the type of a message in an if statement, TypeScript can narrow down the type to `SimpleMessage | Implementation`:

```
/* type of message is AnyMessage */
if (message.type === MessageType.Foo) 
{
   /* type of message is SimpleMessage | Implementation */
}
```

It should be noted that there will only ever be one implementation for each `MessageType`, and there will be some `MessageType`s that have no implementation.

How can I narrow down the type from `SimpleMessage | Implementation` to `Implementation`?

Comment: Remove SimpleMessage from the union type? But why do you need this type property and this union type in the first place? Why don't you use polymorphism?

Comment: @JBNizet I don't want to rely on polymorphism because these objects are going to be serialized (with JSON.Stringify). I can't remove `SimpleMessage` from the union type because there are cases where objects with the type are `SimpleMessage`s.